# url rewriting for address bar in php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to just url rewriting in address bar from

```
https://www.tinycent.com/web/single_post.php?slug=samsung-sprint
```

to

```
https://www.tinycent.com/web/single_post/samsung-sprint
```

Any one can help me for this thing it's need to in better way also i had saw

More 10 demo at stackoverflow or other but he doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: Hey Kamran Please Check this screenshot please http://prntscr.com/724yhf

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^web/single_post/([^/]*)$ /web/single_post.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey Kamran Thanks's to Reply but issues does not solve                                             i mean that's not work.......

Comment: can you share your directory structure so it will give a better idea and please make sure Apache mod redirect is enabled on your server.

Comment: https://www.tinycent.com/web/single_post.php?slug=IPL-2015-RCB-v-MI-Highlights,   web is subfolder for testing, and single_post.php i just need to url https://www.tinycent.com/web/IPL-2015-RCB-v-MI-Highlights

Comment: can you share your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/web/single_post/([^/]*)$ /web/single_post.php?slug=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^107\.180\.2\.62
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.tinycent.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tinycent.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: add the `.htaccess` in your question and try to comment other two rules and test if it works.

Comment: please check this url http://prntscr.com/724yhf

Comment: @user2727842 - You can remove the forward slash from `^/web` so that it becomes `^web` and it will work. @Kamran - please update your answer.

Comment: @MikeRockett updated. Thanks for correction. I have edited the answer.